# Is there a way to make the \not slash strike in the direction of this: \ and not this: /?

Tags: formatting

I would like to use `\not`, but let the slash strike backward `\`, not forward `/`. How can achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\mynot[1]{%
  \mathrel%
  {%
    \ooalign{\hidewidth$\backslash$\hidewidth\cr$#1$}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
  \[ a\mynot{=}b\]

  \[a\mynot{\geq}b\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `\backnot` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\backnot{\mathrel{\mathpalette\back@not\relax}}
\newcommand\back@not[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \kern\wd\z@
    \reflectbox{$\m@th#1\not$}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$a\not= b_{\not=}$

$a\backnot= b_{\backnot=}$
\end{document}
```

[image]